# How to get a webform submission by uuid in a custom controller before submit?

Tags: webforms

Before we submit our multi step webform, we do a ajax call to a custom controller. Ideally this controller would set some of submission values "under the hood".

What we try to achieve is to "extend" webform into supporting asynchronous payments like paypal. On the "billing step" the customer authorizes against paypal and the relevant values are stored in theform without routing through the customers browser to be tempered with.

The problem is, that at this point of time the submission is not jet stored in the database, so we have no submission id, only the submission uuid. How can we get the specific submission in the controller, before it was submitted?

This returns an empty array before submission:

```php
class CustomController extends ControllerBase {

  public function customaction(Request $request) {

    $params = $request->query->all();
    $suuid = $params['suuid'];

    $res = Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('webform_submission')->loadByProperties(
     ['uuid' => $suuid]
    );

    // $res is an empty array here []
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't believe it's possible. But maybe there's a way to do what you need after the submission is saved? More context could be helpful here, I think.

Comment: Thx Miloš, I edited the asnwer to be a bit more specific about the actual usecase.